# Ways of sending data between FastAPI router methods / endpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, fastapi, httpx

Let's say we have two minimal Fast API endpoints:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import httpx
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/api/endpoint_1")
async def endpoint_1(attributes):
    # process the attributes
    return attributes


@router.get("/api/endpoint_2")
async def endpoint_2():
    # here I need to receive the attributes from POST
    attributes = get_attributes_from_somewhere()

    url = f"http://some_external_service_url.com/api/{urlencode(attributes, doseq=True)}"
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url)
        return response.json().get("items")
```

Now imagine some client does a `POST` request against `endpoint_1` with some `attributes`. I need to take these attributes and use them inside `endpoint_2` to make some further requests to some external services. The data returned by `endpoint_2` is then going to be retrieved by my frontend and rendered to the user.

What's the best recommended way to send the data from `endpoint_1` to `endpoint_2` in Fast API?

I've thought about the following:

- Save the data in some local DB in `endpoint_1` and retrieve it back in `endpoint_2`. After retrieving the data, delete the attributes from DB. This seems like having a lot of overhead for just keeping one table that's really ever going to have one record.
- Save the data using some cache mechanism (Redis / Memcached) but then again, configuring this just to keep this seems also peculiar.

To have a bigger picture about this, I'm using Fast API + Python 3.9 on the backend to create a REST service, along with the `httpx` library to make async requests to external services. On the other side, for frontend I'm using React and Typescript. The frontend is only ever going to call `endpoint_2` to display the `items`. `endpoint_1` is only going to be called by some client service.

Comment: You can use `sqlite` as a simple database that can be shared across processes. Then it becomes a case of durability. It has built-in support in Python, is backed by a single file and allows reads from multiple processes at the same time

Comment: I think you could make a function/class with the code for your endpoint_2 and call it in endpoint_2 and endpoint_1. This way the response from the endpoints will be the same. If you not want to call the external API every time, you could use sqlite (mentioned in the other comment) or even save a json file and define to only call the external API if X hours have passed for example.
I don't think call an endpoint from another endpoint would be good.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you need, but  I thought your POST response would be the same as the get. Anyway, json or sqlite would be fine. The function (which calls the external API) could be on POST and then it will update your json/sqlite and the GET endpoint only need to read and return it.